# Will "PostgreSQL Streaming Replication" fit this use case?

Tags: postgresql, replication, database-replication

I am designing an application for public organizations.

The purpose is to record data (text and video streams) which will be produced in "local" offices, where connectivity is not guaranteed, and where the power will be available only during the occurrences of meetings.

One of the requisites of the project is the "locality" of the data storage, since data is considered "sensitive" and "important".

One second requisite of the project is to publish to a web server a portion of the data produced during the meetings.

The database server shall be PostgreSQL.

I plan to set up a second PostgreSQL database server on the web infrastructure hosting the web server, and synchronize it with the "local" database.

The "public" database will be accessed only by *selection queryes" (no writes).

I see PostgreSQL does implement "Streaming Replication" [PostgreSQL Streaming Replication](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Streaming_Replication) since version 9.0.

The question(s):

*Is* [PostgreSQL Streaming Replication](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Streaming_Replication) *ready for primetime?

Does it fit the use case I describe above?

Should I expect any major problem?

Could you suggest alternative, better solutions?*

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is the best solution for your case you should know that

- the master database and standby database will be 100% identiques
- standby database will not allow to write (read only)

If you have the configuration of master - standby you will not have problems , but if you use master - master configuration , it may cause some problems .

Comment: Yes, sorry, I did just update my answer adding the "selection queryes only" for the standby database... :-)

Comment: yes generaly we use straming replication to visualise data only (reporting for example)